# Como sacar el resultado de una peticion sql en node js

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, nodejs

estoy haciendo una app en node, y tengo el código para insertar un nuevo usuario, esto me devuelve un id de usuario pero me gustaria saber como puedo hacer para sacar el id fuera de mi función, estoy usando una conexión con sqlserver, os paso mi código:

```
  let idUsuarioNuevo = async() => {
    let idBuena = await sql.connect(config, (err) => {
        if (err) console.log('Error en la conexión con la base de datos', err);
        let db = new sql.Request();

        let nuevoUser = `if not exists (select * from tbl_usuarios_prueba where usuario = '${usuario.usuario}')
        begin
            insert into tbl_usuarios_prueba (usuario, email, password, estado, rol, google) values ('${usuario.usuario}', '${usuario.email}', '${usuario.password}', '${usuario.estado}', ${usuario.rol}, '${usuario.google}')

            select id from tbl_usuarios_prueba where usuario = '${usuario.usuario}'
        end
       else
        begin
            select id from tbl_usuarios_prueba where usuario = '${usuario.usuario}'
        end`;


        let idUser = db.query(nuevoUser, (err, data) => {
            if (err) console.log('Error al crear el nuevo usuario');
            let id = data.recordset[0].id;
        });

        return idUsuarioNuevo;
    });

    return idBuena;
}

idUsuarioNuevo().then(id => {
    console.log('id => ', id);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('error');
});
```

No soy capaz de hacer que la id salga fuera de esa función, como puedo solucionar eso?? muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Tu problema es que estás mezclando [Promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise) con [Callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Callback_function), por lo tanto el resultado esperado no es el deseado.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una solución es eliminar el uso de funciones `callback` y usar el operador [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/await) para cada procedimiento asíncrono. Además, dado que cada método de la librería [`mssql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) devuelve una Promesa, debes usar siempre [`try ... catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/try...catch) para manejar dichas Promesas.

Por ejemplo:

```js
let idUsuarioNuevo = async () => { // función tipo async devolverá una Promesa
  try {
      await sql.connect(config); // conectamos a la DB
      let db = new sql.Request();
      let nuevoUser = `if not exists (select * from tbl_usuarios_prueba where usuario = '${usuario.usuario}')
        begin
            insert into tbl_usuarios_prueba (usuario, email, password, estado, rol, google) values ('${usuario.usuario}', '${usuario.email}', '${usuario.password}', '${usuario.estado}', '${usuario.rol}', '${usuario.google}')
            select id from tbl_usuarios_prueba where usuario = '${usuario.usuario}'
        end
       else
        begin
            select id from tbl_usuarios_prueba where usuario = '${usuario.usuario}'
        end`;
      let result = await db.query(nuevoUser); // almacenamos el resultado de la Promesa
      let id = result.recordset[0].id; // Obtenemos el id
      return id; // devolvemos el resultado
  } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
      throw err;
  }
}

idUsuarioNuevo() // es una Promesa, podemos usar then() y cacth()
.then(id => {
  console.log(`El id generado es: ${id}`);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(`Hubo un error`);
});
```

**Sentencias preparadas**

Una mejora que puedes hacer en tu código, por motivos de seguridad es usar [sentencias preparadas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#prepared-statement). Esto para minimizar el riesgo de ataques tipo [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).

Por ejemplo, tu código podría verse de la siguiente forma:

```js
let idUsuarioNuevo = async () => {
  try {
    await sql.connect(config);
    const prepStmnt = new sql.PreparedStatement(); // sentencia preparada

    // definimos los parámetros (los valores dependerán de la DDL de tu tabla)
    prepStmnt.input('usuario', sql.VarChar(50));
    prepStmnt.input('email', sql.VarChar(50));
    prepStmnt.input('password', sql.VarChar(50));
    prepStmnt.input('estado', sql.VarChar(20));
    prepStmnt.input('rol', sql.VarChar(20));
    prepStmnt.input('google', sql.VarChar(255));

    // definimos la consulta SQL usando @param según sea necesario
    let nuevoUser = `if not exists (select * from tbl_usuarios_prueba where usuario = @usuario)
      begin
        insert into tbl_usuarios_prueba (usuario, email, password, estado, rol, google) values (@usuario, @email, @password, @estado, @rol, @google)
        select id from tbl_usuarios_prueba where usuario = @usuario
      end
    else
      begin
        select id from tbl_usuarios_prueba where usuario = @usuario
      end`;

    // preparamos la sentencia    
    await prepStmnt.prepare(nuevoUser);

    // ejecutamos la sentencia pasando como parámetro el objeto 'usuario'
    // que contiene los valores de cada campo:
    // usuario = {usuario: 'valor, email: 'valor', ..., google: 'valor'}
    let result = await prepStmnt.execute(usuario);

    // cerramos la conexión
    await prepStmnt.unprepare();

    // trabajamos con el resultado
    console.dir(result);
    let id = result.recordset[0].id;
    return id;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw err;
  }
}

idUsuarioNuevo()
.then(id => {
  console.log(`El id generado es: ${id}`);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(`Hubo un error`);
})
```

Con esto ya puedes trabajar con el valor `id` devuelto por la Promesa.

**Nota**

En tu sentencia SQL tienes un error, te falta envolver el valor `${usuario.rol}` entre comillas simples:

```
...','${usuario.rol}', '...
```

Otra recomendación es referente al campo `password`. No veo que hagas un proceso de [`hash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) del mismo. No es nada recomendable que almacenes la contraseña en texto plano en la base de datos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, en cuanto a la encriptación, ese archivo era uno de prueba, ahora estoy usando bcrypt para encriptar, muchas gracias.

Comment: Pero si añado este código:

    let idUsuario = idUsuarioNuevo().then(id => {
        return id;
    }).catch(err => console.log('Error al crear un nuevo usuario'));

    console.log(`id = ${idUsuario}`);

obtengo id = [object Promise]

como puedo guardar en esa variable el id?? muchas gracias

Comment: No puedes, la función es `async`, la variable sólo vive dentro del método `then()`. Se que es difícil de entender, pero es la forma de trabajar con procesos asíncronos. Un truco es envolver todo tu código en una función asíncrona y así poder usar la sentencia `await`. Por ejemplo: `idNuevo = await idUsuarioNuevo();`. Saludos